# Dynamically change the column arrangement in bootstrap while retaining responsiveness

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an area on my page which I spawn cards of definite sizes(250*250).But I want it to be maximum 4 cards per row(on small viewport I will stack them). for now, it works with 4 cards and more(the excess will break and goes the other line, all good). but the problem is when I have less than 4 cards(it may occur). The cards come from a database which I produce at run-time. This is a rails application by the way.

I want the cards to align themselves while maintaining their size inside the row if there less than 4 cards by having more margin to their right and left.

The design I have in mind is this for 4 or more cards:

[image]

and for less than 4, for example for 2 cards like this:

[image]

This is what happens when I have for example 2 cards:
[image]

And this is what I have for 5 cards:
[image]

The margin, I can work with.

---

**Question:**
How can I work this out to have only 4 fixed-size columns on large screens, and on smalls stack them up. while being dynamically aligning themselves if there are less than 4 cards in the row.

This is what I have done so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="feature-wrapper pt-5 pb-5 mt-5 mt-lg-0 h-100 ">

<div class="d-flex align-items-center h-100 justify-content-center ">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="my-card col-sm-12 col-lg-3 text-center mb-3 mb-md-0 rounded border">
            <i class="far fa-plus-square fa-10x"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="my-card col-sm-12 col-lg-3 text-center mb-3 mb-md-0 rounded border">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-down fa-10x"></i>
        </div>
         <div class="my-card col-sm-12 col-lg-3 text-center mb-3 mb-md-0 rounded border">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-down fa-10x"></i>
        </div>
         <div class="my-card col-sm-12 col-lg-3 text-center mb-3 mb-md-0 rounded border">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-down fa-10x"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body,html{
  height:100%;
}
.my-card{
      height:250px;
      width:250px;
      background-color:red;
      text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Comment: @ChandraShekhar There you go : https://www.bootply.com/6iJKAspYqv

Comment: try this add "    justify-content: space-between;" to the row

Comment: @ChandraShekhar Still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be difficult to get this *exact* layout using the Bootstrap grid, because of the fixed size cards. If you add a little CSS you can get the flexbox rows to size exactly according to card width...

https://www.codeply.com/go/AbMj2VVo1H

```
.flex-shrink {
  flex:0 0 1000px;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .flex-shrink {
    flex:0 0 500px;
  }
}
```

If you can allow more flexbility with the card size not being exactly 250px, then the Bootstrap grid will work: https://www.codeply.com/go/JmHRmJ5CYD

A last option is the auto-layout grid columns which will fit to the size of the cards, but won't give you the exact 4 cards, and then 2 cards on mobile: https://www.codeply.com/go/xLXsbRSaMB

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Can you provide more information about the flex-shrink class?

Comment: It sets the `flex-basis` based on the desired width of the cards. 250X4 = 1000px for largers screens, and then on screens less than 768px, it is 500X2 - 500px.